# Is it possible to create an age estimation by face program using deeplearning with my laptop?

Tags: machine-learning

My computer specs:
Processor type  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @1.80GHz 1.99GHz
Installed RAM   8.00 GB
System Type     64 bit operating system
i also have Intel UHD graphics 620.

I am starting an AI course in college and we have been given the project to submit by the end of the semester. i want to use deep learning but i want to make sure its possible  to do it using my laptop so i dont run into problems later on that will jeopardize my progress. Btw i will also use a GPU instance on Amazon E2c or Google laboratory.

Comment: You should try to use a GPU to the extent possible -- it can speed up the execution of deep networks by orders of magnitude.

Comment: so its not enough to use the GPU instance

Comment: I misread your question, I thought you were asking about running only on CPU.